ROS Navigation robot_description
I'm trying to do navigation in ROS, when i run navigation there is error that [parameter [robot_description] does not exist and was not found by searchparam] when i checked the tf tree, there are map->odom->base_footprint->base_link-> laser and imu_link my navigation launch file also launch move_base or motor launch file. can anyone tell me the reason of this problem and solution?
enter image description here
I tried to check files about description but I can't find what is the reason of this robot_description error.
